# Delete records only older than 50 rows while grouping by 1 column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have 21 dealers having records.  Some dealers have records greater than 50 rows.  As part of the required house-keeping cleanup, I need to delete records that are greater/older than 50 records per dealer but keep records #1 to #50.

I can't wrap my head around that.  I see few options, 1) group by dealer id, 2) order by timestamp

Thanks

```
---Schema Fields---
ID               bigint
SearchID         bigint
AccountID        bigint
UserID           bigint
VIN              varchar
Year             varchar
Make             varchar
Model            varchar
Trim             varchar
[TimeStamp]      datetime
--------------------
```

AccountID is the dealer id.  ID is the target record identifier to delete from.  TimeStamp is use as OrderBy.

Comment: Schema, whereforth are you?

Comment: Just edit the post to include schema info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the fact that you provided no table schema, lets say the table looks something like

```
MyDealersTable
- DealerID
- SomeOtherColumn
- DealerMotherName
- DealerSportInterest
- SomeTimeStamp
```

You can try something like

```
;WITH Dealers AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DealerID ORDER BY SomeTimeStamp DESC) RowID
    FROM MyDealersTable
)
DELETE 
FROM Dealers
WHERE RowID > 50
```

From [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table
>   expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined
>   within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement.

Comment: SQL Server throwing a fit (or error) when using "ORDER BY" in OVER() function.

Comment: Sorry, try it without the comma after DealerID before the ORDER BY,  something like http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18777

Comment: Nice.  That works great!!  I'm familiar with CTE.  Row_Number() is something I can learn how to use.  :-)